# How to use child class @Html.TextBoxFor and post with parent class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model

We have a MasterClass contains all other class objects..

```
public class MasterClass
{
 public ChildClass1 Class1{get;set;}

 public ChildClass2 Class2{get;set;}
}

public class ChildClass1 
{
 public string myclass1property1{get;set;}
 public string myclass1property2{get;set;}

}


public class ChildClass2 
{
 public string myclass2property1{get;set;}
 public string myclass2property2{get;set;}

}
```

**On the Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult Post(MasterClass master)
{
   // here we are fetching the master class object.

}
```

On **MyChildClass1View.cshtml**

```
@model MasterClass

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyChildClass1 View"; 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; 
}
 <div class="form-group">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.ChildClass1.myclass1property1, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text" })
 </div>
```

In Above instead of written hole length name i want to render as below
Instead of this
**

> Model.ChildClass1.myclass1property1

**
I want to **

> Model.myclass1property1

**

I have tried with

> var model = Model.ChildClass1

But not working it returning all value blank on POST action.

can you suggest anyone have idea on it?

Comment: You cannot (unless you create `EditorTemplate`'s for `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2`). Inorder to bind to your model, the `name` attribute must match the qualified name of the property, which means you must generate `name="Class1.myclass2property1"` Why do you think you want to change it?

Comment: @StephenMuecke can I suppress the class1 generate in HTML output?

Comment: But why - that will just mean that you cannot bind to the model in the POST method. Its not clear what your trying to do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can i render property without Class1. prefix on HTML?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Is it possible to render name attribute without prefix class name. ?

Comment: Again, why would you want to do that? It would mean that you cannot bind to your model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166312/discussion-between-abhishek-b-and-stephen-muecke).